# Is it better to exclude non essential words in Google searches

Tags: google-search

For example, if I had a question about iMovie, should I search Google:

```
How to add transitions to multiple clips in iMovie
```

Or something like:

```
Add transitions multiple clips iMovie
```

Comment: I leave them out, makes typing  faster but google is smart enough to give basically the same results for both query's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Moab mentioned, the Google algorithms are pretty smart, and will often bring up the same results, I would check out [Google's own explanation](https://www.google.co.uk/insidesearch/howsearchworks/thestory/) if you want more details.

When it comes to optimising search methods, its often best to use [Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search).

Notice the "To do this in the search box" section on the right - learn these methods and you can perform your own advanced searches from any Google search box without using the Advanced Search page. The full list of symbols and operators can be found on the [Search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en) page.

Comment: Thanks, I especially appreciate the link to [Google's own explanation](https://www.google.co.uk/insidesearch/howsearchworks/thestory/).

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by Sam3000, using the Advanced search is a way to learn how to perform these advanced methods from the search box.

You should avoid the non essential words like "a", "to", etc, but Google generally ignores them.

For your search, I would write:

```
"add transitions" "multiple clips" imovie
```

This make sure that "add transitions" and "multiple clips" are considered as a specific action and a qualified noun.  You avoid search results where "add transistions" and "multiple clips" do not occur in the text.

Sometimes Google will remove those quotes before rendering the seach results - most of the time because no results were found with the quotes, in some cases because there were "too few" results.  In the latter case you need to request google to search with the quotes, and you should check for typing errors and possible remove a search term.

If you add the non essential words inside the quotes, google will not ignore them.
A search for

```
"How to add transitions to multiple clips in iMovie"
```

will currently provide your question in the search results.

```
"How to" "add transitions" "to multiple clips" "in iMovie"
```

will give a few more results, but "in iMovie" is too specific.

```
"How to" "add transitions" "to multiple clips" "iMovie"
```

is better, even though the "How to" may exclude a lot of results.  Not all writers think about putting "How to" in their tip.